# Como declarar cadeias "strings" acentuadas?

Tags: c, lua, prisma

Lua é escrita em C logo compartilha o Código Padrão Americano para Intercâmbio de Informações "ASCII"

Aceita declaração de chave de matriz com acento:

```
rafael = {}
rafael["é"]="eu"
print(rafael["é"])

--saída:     eu
```

Mas como fazer declaração de cadeias "string" com acento ?

```
é="eu"      -- é possível ?
```

Comment: Mesmo não tendo conhecimento em prisma desde já digo que nomes de variáveis com acentos é sempre má ideia. Não há vantagem pois são nomes internos e apenas visíveis ao programador e é sempre mais um motivo para possíveis problemas com codificações.

Comment: Na verdade você quer identificadores acentuados (má ideia, concordo com o @Isac). Acentos em strings você já viu que funcionam.

Comment: Nao use acentos para nomes de variaveis.

Answer (score 1):

**Terminologia**. No seu exemplo `é="eu"`, você chamaria `é` de um *identificador* ou *nome*.

**Respondendo**. Um código Lua se divide em: gramática e síntaxe. A síntaxe depende da gramática (como único objetivo lexical, no Lua). Na gramática do Lua só é possível introduzir o caractere **é** dentro de comentários e cadeias de strings, porque suas produções não se importam com todos caracteres (só delimitadores, se for o caso).

Fora isso, não é possível introduzir o caractere **é** e respondido. Lua não tem nada haver com C.

Definição lexical de um nome Lua (baseada no ECMA-357 2º):

*Name* ::

- *NameRepeat* mas nenhuma palavra-chave

*NameRepeat* ::

- *NameStart*
- *NameRepeat* *NameRepeat*

*NameStart* ::

- Qualquer letra latina (A-Z ou a-z) no ASCII
- **_**

*NamePart* ::

- *NameStart*
- Qualquer digito do ASCII

Ou seja, um identificador consiste de letras normais do ASCII e/ou _ (traços) e opcionalmente continua com digitos. Isso é o que o manual diz.

Comment: Quando eu escrevi "derivada" me referi aos fontes que são escritos em C. Não que ela pegou o C e modificou.

Comment: @RafaelLemos Ou você quis dizer _implementação_...

Comment: @RafaelLemos Se você quer colocar `é` num identificador, há várias alternativas: JavaScript, XML, Java e blah.

Comment: Muito bom, javascript eu já sabia. O problema de ficar escrevendo o português sem acento é que depois eu fico confuso e não sei nem mais se a palavra tem acento ou não. Isso me deixa doido!

Comment: @RafaelLemos Na real, não sou muito fã de misturar Português com códigos. Talvez pq a pessoa quer variar de linguagem de tanto cansar da nativa. Mas, realmente, parece que Español é melhor hueahueahuea brinks slá